# Setting deep associations in normalizr schema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, normalizr

I have a server response that looks like this:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  title: 'Some Article',
  related_articles: {
    total: 4,
    results: [
      { id: 2, title: 'Some other article' },
      { id: 3, title: 'Yet another article' },
    ]
  }
}]
```

As you can see, what makes this tricky is it isn't a simple `arrayOf`: I want to normalize `article.related_articles.results`.

I've tried this, to no avail:

```
articleSchema.define({
  related_articles: {
    results: arrayOf(relatedArticleSchema),
  },
});
```

It seems as though supported relations have to be "top level".

Anyone know how I can wind up with something like:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  title: 'Some Article',
  related_articles: {
    total: 4,
    results: [2, 3]
  }
}]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scheme defines a key "relatedArticles", but it should be snake_case, "related_articles"

Comment: Ah, embarrassingly it looks like the issue was simpler than that; I just needed to restart my server, since that view is server-rendered, so my changes weren't actually being propagated. Sorry, and thanks!